# How to override button.phtml from Module_Backend in own module

Tags: magento2, module, template, overrides

I want to override following file in my custom module:

> module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/wiget/button.phtml

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a module for this.

Using plugin on class `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button` over `getTemplate` method, you can achieve your requirement.

Plugin class `WidgetButtonPlugin.php` located at `app\code\{Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\Plugin\Block`.

**Plugin class code look like**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\Plugin\Block;

class WidgetButtonPlugin
{

    public function aftergetTemplate(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        return '{Vendorname}_{CompanyName}::widget/button.phtml';
    }

}
```

Plugin's  `di.xml` should be located at  `app\code\{Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\etc`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button">
        <plugin name="changes_button_template_file_for_widget" sortOrder="1"
                type="{Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\Plugin\Block\WidgetButtonPlugin" />
    </type>

</config>
```

As per as, plugin new template should be located at

`app\code\{Vendorname}\{CompanyName}\view\adminhtml\templates\wiget\button.phtml`

Comment: I try that soon, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your custom admin theme

[Create an Admin theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html)